# How to create statistics with DIV, IMGs in PHP&CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create "statistics" with two images which are 1x1px, these will be resized if the value changes. The problem is that I have a "actual value" & a "target value". The actual value will be green & the target value yellow.

I thought about creating two div with the background colors, or puting one img on the other img. But if i resize the yellow one the hole thing goes down the page and not up. I tried with position: relative; and position: absolut; without success.

Any idea how i should do that?

here is an example img.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepsX.jpg
[image]

Thanks

Comment: you should use JavaScript for that. simply add two divs with background color, and resize them dynamically..

Comment: Using divs and CSS, and updating with jQuery will do the trick. Now unless you want to learn, use an existing charts library. Reinventing the wheel is not such a good idea usually.